# Loop Operação com Múltiplos Data Frames

Tags: r, loop, data.frame

Supondo o seguinte exemplo no `R`:

```
Sample_data <- data.table(code = c("AAPL","AAPL","AAPL", "AMZN","AMZN","AMZN", "MSFT","MSFT", "GOOG","GOOG","GOOG", "FB"), date = c("2019-12-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2019-12-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2019-12-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2019-12-01"), price = c(292.9,295.4,293.6, 1847.4,1849.3,1845.4, 157.2,159.1, 1337.1,1335.8,1333.7, 205.2 ) )
```

Preciso:

**Primeiro:** Separar os dados em data frames diferentes tendo como critério a coluna "code", isto é, neste exemplo, terei 5 data frames diferentes para cada código (3x2 para AAPL, 1x2 para FB, etc).

Para isso, fiz o seguinte:

```
plist <- unique(Sample_data$code)
  lst <- setNames(vector("list", length(plist)), plist)
  for (i in plist) {
    assign(i, Sample_data %>% select(code,date,price) %>% filter(code %in% i))
  }
```

**Segundo:** preciso executar uma operação numérica dentro de cada data frame e adicionar o resultado dela em uma nova coluna dentro do mesmo dataframe para cada um deles.

O problema está sendo este segundo passo, no qual a minha ideia é gerar uma lista com os dataframes gerados e incluir os valores da operação, mas não sei como.

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário aplicar *loops* para fazer o que deseja. Com `tidyverse` você pode fazer isso.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

**Primeiro:** Separar os dados em data frames diferentes tendo como critério a coluna "code", isto é, neste exemplo, terei 5 data frames diferentes para cada código (3x2 para AAPL, 1x2 para FB, etc).

Você pode fazer isso com a função `group_split`:

```
lista <- Sample_data %>% 
  group_split(.tbl = ., code, .keep = TRUE)
```

**Segundo:** preciso executar uma operação numérica dentro de cada data frame e adicionar o resultado dela em uma nova coluna dentro do mesmo dataframe para cada um deles.

Vou criar uma nova coluna com as funções `mutate` e `across`, esta última recentemente adicionada ao pacote `dplyr` para substituir/ unificar as funções com sufixos `all`, `at` e `if`. Leia mais sobre ela [aqui](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/).

Talvez `across` não funcione em sua versão atual do `dplyr`. Para resolver isto, basta:

```
remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```

Por fim, a análise. Vou somar a variável `price` com a função `sum`:

```
lista %>% 
  map(.x = ., .f = ~ mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = c('price'), .fns = list(~ sum(.)))))
```

Resultado:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code  date       price price_1
  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 AAPL  2019-12-01  293.    882.
2 AAPL  2020-01-01  295.    882.
3 AAPL  2020-02-01  294.    882.

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code  date       price price_1
  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 AMZN  2019-12-01 1847.   5542.
2 AMZN  2020-01-01 1849.   5542.
3 AMZN  2020-02-01 1845.   5542.

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  code  date       price price_1
  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 FB    2019-12-01  205.    205.

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code  date       price price_1
  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 GOOG  2019-12-01 1337.   4007.
2 GOOG  2020-01-01 1336.   4007.
3 GOOG  2020-02-01 1334.   4007.

[[5]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  code  date       price price_1
  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 MSFT  2020-01-01  157.    316.
2 MSFT  2020-02-01  159.    316.
```

Answer (score 0):

Como está usando `data.table`, não é necessário, nem recomendável, dividir os dados em diferentes data.frames; é melhor fazer operações por grupo.

```
library(data.table)

# Resumo dos dados por grupo

> Sample_data[, .(sum_price = sum(price)), by = code]
   code sum_price
1: AAPL     881.9
2: AMZN    5542.1
3: MSFT     316.3
4: GOOG    4006.6
5:   FB     205.2

# Criar uma nova coluna por grupo

Sample_data[, sum_price := sum(price), by = code]

> Sample_data
    code       date  price sum_price
 1: AAPL 2019-12-01  292.9     881.9
 2: AAPL 2020-01-01  295.4     881.9
 3: AAPL 2020-02-01  293.6     881.9
 4: AMZN 2019-12-01 1847.4    5542.1
 5: AMZN 2020-01-01 1849.3    5542.1
 6: AMZN 2020-02-01 1845.4    5542.1
 7: MSFT 2020-01-01  157.2     316.3
 8: MSFT 2020-02-01  159.1     316.3
 9: GOOG 2019-12-01 1337.1    4006.6
10: GOOG 2020-01-01 1335.8    4006.6
11: GOOG 2020-02-01 1333.7    4006.6
12:   FB 2019-12-01  205.2     205.2
```

Se precisar realmente separar os dados em uma lista de data.tables, pode usar a função `data.table::split`, mas é sempre mais eficiente fazer operações por grupos.

```
> split(Sample_data, by = 'code')
$AAPL
   code       date price sum_price
1: AAPL 2019-12-01 292.9     881.9
2: AAPL 2020-01-01 295.4     881.9
3: AAPL 2020-02-01 293.6     881.9

$AMZN
   code       date  price sum_price
1: AMZN 2019-12-01 1847.4    5542.1
2: AMZN 2020-01-01 1849.3    5542.1
3: AMZN 2020-02-01 1845.4    5542.1

$MSFT
   code       date price sum_price
1: MSFT 2020-01-01 157.2     316.3
2: MSFT 2020-02-01 159.1     316.3

$GOOG
   code       date  price sum_price
1: GOOG 2019-12-01 1337.1    4006.6
2: GOOG 2020-01-01 1335.8    4006.6
3: GOOG 2020-02-01 1333.7    4006.6

$FB
   code       date price sum_price
1:   FB 2019-12-01 205.2     205.2
```

Se preferir a sintaxe e funções do tidyverse, é melhor usar *tibble* como formato para as tabelas de dados; o uso de data.table nesse caso não trará nenhum ganho. Em ambos os casos, manter os dados em uma única tabela e fazer operações por grupo é preferível a separar os dados.

```
library(dplyr)

Sample_data <- tibble(code = c("AAPL","AAPL","AAPL", "AMZN","AMZN","AMZN", "MSFT","MSFT", "GOOG","GOOG","GOOG", "FB"), date = c("2019-12-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2019-12-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2019-12-01","2020-01-01","2020-02-01", "2019-12-01"), price = c(292.9,295.4,293.6, 1847.4,1849.3,1845.4, 157.2,159.1, 1337.1,1335.8,1333.7, 205.2 ) )

> Sample_data %>% group_by(code) %>% summarise(sum_price = sum(price))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  code  sum_price
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 AAPL       882.
2 AMZN      5542.
3 FB         205.
4 GOOG      4007.
5 MSFT       316.

Sample_data %<>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(sum_price = sum(price))

> Sample_data
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   code [5]
   code  date       price sum_price
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 AAPL  2019-12-01  293.      882.
 2 AAPL  2020-01-01  295.      882.
 3 AAPL  2020-02-01  294.      882.
 4 AMZN  2019-12-01 1847.     5542.
 5 AMZN  2020-01-01 1849.     5542.
 6 AMZN  2020-02-01 1845.     5542.
 7 MSFT  2020-01-01  157.      316.
 8 MSFT  2020-02-01  159.      316.
 9 GOOG  2019-12-01 1337.     4007.
10 GOOG  2020-01-01 1336.     4007.
11 GOOG  2020-02-01 1334.     4007.
12 FB    2019-12-01  205.      205.

> Sample_data %>% group_by(code) %>% group_split()
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code  date       price sum_price
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 AAPL  2019-12-01  293.      882.
2 AAPL  2020-01-01  295.      882.
3 AAPL  2020-02-01  294.      882.

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code  date       price sum_price
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 AMZN  2019-12-01 1847.     5542.
2 AMZN  2020-01-01 1849.     5542.
3 AMZN  2020-02-01 1845.     5542.

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  code  date       price sum_price
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 FB    2019-12-01  205.      205.

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code  date       price sum_price
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 GOOG  2019-12-01 1337.     4007.
2 GOOG  2020-01-01 1336.     4007.
3 GOOG  2020-02-01 1334.     4007.

[[5]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  code  date       price sum_price
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 MSFT  2020-01-01  157.      316.
2 MSFT  2020-02-01  159.      316.

attr(,"ptype")
# A tibble: 0 x 4
# … with 4 variables: code <chr>, date <chr>, price <dbl>, sum_price <dbl>
```